# TypeError: cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser(...).promise is not a function

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, promise, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

```
async getUserDetails(accessToken, callback) {
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

var params = {
  AccessToken: accessToken
};

return cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        } else {
            //console.log(data);
            return data;
        }
}).promise();}
```

I am trying to use a .promise() on cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser but seems that despite what documentation says at [docs.aws.amazon.com](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#getUser-property) I get an AWS.Response and not a AWS.Request and using promise on it does not work.

Any idea why this is not working and how I can get User Attributes in an async way in order to use info at a later point?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You are using both callbacks and promises which is why things aren't working. If you want to use `.promise()` you cannot pass a callback to any AWS SDK methods.

Try this:

```
const getUserDetails = async(accessToken) => {
    const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

    const params = {
      AccessToken: accessToken
    };

    return await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser(params).promise();
}
```